# Solr spellcheck and stem filter

Tags: solr, lucene, spell-checking, solrcloud

I've a schema where all the fields are filtered using an italian stem filter.

When I use spellcheck filter, obviously, the filter return a word that was not in the original documents, but that is created by the filter, giving a suggestion that will match with a results but that has no sense.

How can I do?
Have I to use copy fields to do this or I have a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use different fields for different purposes - i.e. use a non-stemmed field and `copyField` the content into that field as well. This is usually by far the simplest solution, as it allows you to keep configuration and field definitions separate, and can be extended as necessary if you need further processing of the values or different spellcheck handling.